# Position: fixed scrolls too far

Tags: html, css, margin, css-position

My question is about the layout in this image:

[image]

- White box in upper right corner = content box
- The black line at the bottom = footer bar
- The box to the right = the sidebar box

The sidebar is set with CSS to `position: fixed`, so it will follow the users scroll.

The problem is, on small screen sizes, the user can scroll too far, meaning that the sidebar box, will go futher down than the footer bar.

How can I make the sidebar stop 20 pixels before hitting the footer?

**CSS Code:**

```
div#sidebar
{
margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
width: 270px;
height: 295px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
background-color:#FFF;
padding: 20px;
position:fixed;
left: 730px;
}

div#content
{
margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
width: 650px;
height: 600px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
background-color:#FFF;
float: left;
padding: 20px;
}

div#footer
{
width: 100%;
min-width:1024px;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid black;
background:#252525;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
color:#555;
}
```

Comment: show us your html and css code

Answer (score 0):

I would try to adjust `#sidebar` `margin-bottom`. What's your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content box to stop getting larger with zoom i think you would have to use javascript. If i understand your problem correctly, that content goes over the footer. Try use this:

```
div#footer
{
width: 100%;
min-width:1024px;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid black;
background:#252525;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
color:#555;
}
```

Comment: Putting in position:relative, to the footer, just make the sidebar box, go behind the footer bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bottom: 20px;` property in your `div#sidebar`.

Comment: This created a new problem, how the sidebar will go to far up. It will scroll all the way up in the header/menu

Comment: In that case, there are only two possible solution I can see. 
1) is you put your side bar in other div (say #sidebar-container)make that div position:fixed and giv it padding-bottom:20px and remove position:fixed from #sidebar;

2) is to use some javsascript that checks the scroll-top every time you scroll and remove position: fixed from the #sidebar and add it back when the scroll moves up. (This is bit complecated and patchy).